# in nx libs, why are module boundaries enforced through public APIs?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

In a typical NX repo, `libs` expose a public API through what gets exported from `index.js`.  I can understand why this is useful (especially if one wanted to publish the library to npm or have a well defined public api for consumption).  However, are there other benefits that I'm not seeing?

If the listed benefits above aren't needed, then is there a reason I couldn't simply import files/methods/variables directly from the lib instead of having to expose them through `index.js`?

```
// typical convention in nx
import { Foo } from '@company/fooLib';

// tsconfig would look something like this
"paths": {
  "@company/fooLib": ["libs/fooLib/src/index.js"],
},

vs.

// import from file directly
import { Foo } from '@company/fooLib/Foo';

// tsconfig would look something like this
"paths": {
  "@company/fooLib/*": ["libs/fooLib/src/*"],
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you use the index.ts to define what is public and what is private within your library. Everything what is public should not contain breaking changes. That means you can do whatever you want inside your lib, as long as you make sure that all the public stuff is downward compatible.

If you have no control what other libraries import from your library, every change can break the functionallity of other libs and you have no clue what is used outside of your lib. That is the main reason to only use index.ts.

Inside of your library you just use the relative imports, but everything from outside should only use the mapped ts path.

In general this is important if multiple teams work together within one monorepo, and libraries have code ownerships to specific teams. And even if you are only work as one team, it is easier for refactoring and moving libraries, because they are loosely coupled and you can see which stuff is used outside your lib and only that needs to be considered.